# Запрос SSDP на unicast остается без ответа

Tags: upnp

SSDP запрос (M-SEARCH) на multicast (239.255.255.250:1900) отрабатывает отлично. Но если я отправляю этот запрос (только без поля MX) на unicast-адрес в локальной сети - upnp-устройство не отвечает. Wireshark показывает, что мой SSDP-запрос действительно отправляется в сеть, но остается без ответа.
Отправка unicast-запроса допускается [SSDP-стандартом](https://openconnectivity.org/upnp-specs/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v2.0-20200417.pdf)

Не могу понять, почему upnp-устройства не отвечают на unicast SSDP-запрос? В чем особенность отправки таких запросов?